# Is it a mistake of Proofs from The Book?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

I saw  the **crossing lemma**  in the forty-five chapter titled *Probability makes counting
(sometimes) easy*.

**Theorem 4.** Let $G$ be a simple graph with n vertices and m edges, where $m \ge 4n$. Then  $${\rm{cr}}(G) \ge \frac{1}{64}\frac{m^3}{n^2}$$
What I am confused about is this sentence, marked in purple:
[image]
We know if $n=1$ , then $cr(K_1)-m+3n=3<6$.
It does not satisfy (4).
[image]

Similarly, $K_2$ is one and the last unsatisfied. Is this a mistake? Is it possible to use other methods to get this result:
$$E(X_p-m_p+3n_p)\ge 0?$$
The link to the electronic version is below.
[Proofs from The Book](https://cn1lib.org/book/3521617/6734d1)

Comment: The inequality being used here is that for planar graphs *with at least $3$ vertices*, with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices, $m \leqslant 3n-6$. Notice the condition on Theorem 4, and conclude that all relevant graphs have at least three vertices.

Comment: @William I was also thinking "all relevant graphs have at least three vertices" until I noticed that this result is being applied to the subsampled graph $G_p$, which could have any number of vertices. So this would actually be a bit of a hole in the proof, except we're only using $m \le 3n$ for that step, and that holds even for $K_1$ and $K_2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I thought about it a little bit more. Isn't the implication $cr(G) -m +3n \geq 0 \implies E(X_p-m_p+3n_p) \geq 0$ still correct? We are using $(4)$ only for using $cr(G) -m +3n \geq 0$. And since $G_p$ is induced, this is true for any number of vertices. I might be mistaken, though.

Comment: @DavidScholz I agree, that's what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your enthusiastic help. I seem to understand the source of the problem. Indeed, applying (4) alone is problematic. (4) only holds for $n \geq 3$.
But $E(X_p-m_p+3n_p)\ge 0$ is still correct .  Since when  $n$ is less than or equal to 2  the formula still holds.

To be more specific.

If $n=1$, then $cr(K_1)-m+3n=3>0$.

If $n=2$, then $cr(K_2)-m+3n=0-2+6=4>0$  and $cr(2K_1)-m+3n=0-0+6>0$

Comment: I think that this reasoning is correct. I've deleted my answer, since its nature is different. We are only using $(4)$ for implying $cr(G) -m +3n \geq 0$.